# Validation not working in Java Spring Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, dto

I added the correct validation annotations to my DTO and API class, but when I input bad data thru postman, it doesn't error.

API Class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/laptops")
@Validated
public class LaptopApi
{
    @Autowired
    private LaptopService laptopService;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<LaptopDTO> getLaptop(@PathVariable Integer id)
    {
        LaptopDTO laptop = laptopService.getLaptop(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(laptop, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<List<LaptopDTO>> getLaptops()
    {
        List<LaptopDTO> laptops = laptopService.getLaptops();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(laptops, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<LaptopDTO> addLaptop(@RequestBody @Valid LaptopDTO laptopDTO)
    {
        Integer laptopId = laptopService.addLaptop(laptopDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(laptopDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<LaptopDTO> updateSpecs(@RequestBody @Valid LaptopDTO laptopDTO)
    {
        laptopService.updateSpecs(laptopDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(laptopDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteLaptop(@PathVariable Integer id)
    {
        laptopService.deleteLaptop(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(environment.getProperty("API.LAPTOP_DELETE_SUCCESS")+" "+id,
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

DTO Class (I ran the regex checks on a unit test, which works correctly)

```
public class LaptopDTO
{
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "(Intel core i[3579] [0-9]{4,}[A-Za-z]*)" +
                        "|(AMD Ryzen [3579] [0-9]{4,}[A-Za-z]*)",
            message = "microcenter.cpu.invalid")
    private String cpu;

    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 4)
    private Integer ram;

    @NotNull
    private Integer nvme;

    @NotNull
    private Integer ssd;

    @NotNull
    private Integer hdd;

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "(Intel U?HD [56][23]0)|" +
                        "([Nn]vidia Geforce [GR]TX [123][06][5678]0)(| super| Ti)",
            message = "microcenter.gpu.invalid")
    private String gpu;
  
   ... //constructors and methods
  }
```

JSON Request Body:

```
{
    "name": "asegjbofld;bsgj",
    "cpu": "radhtrhsth",
    "ram": 2,
    "nvme": 512,
    "ssd": 1000,
    "hdd": 2000,
    "gpu": "newga"
}
```

Based on the invalid cpu and gpu input from the json request body, it is supposed to error, because of the gpu and cpu, but the request gets processed?  Any ideas on how to fix? Thanks.

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.microcenter</groupId>
    <artifactId>MicroCenter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MicroCenter</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? Is it's above 1.4.7, you may have to add `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency. Show us your pom

Comment: pom.xml is posted, and I am using javax.validation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The spring boot version,

```java
    <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

doesn't support `validator-api`,

```java
    <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
         <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

out of the box. Till Spring boot version 1.4.7, `javax.validation` had out-of-the-box support.

You need to add the dependency:

```java
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This will add the required support.

Comment: @Alan Do accept the answer. If helps others let know it worked for you. Happy coding!